# How to put two random images on one page?

Tags: javascript

Here is JS

```
  var images = [
     "",
     "01.jpg",
     "02.jpg",
     "03.jpg"];

function randImg() {
   var size = images.length
   var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
   document.getElementById('image').src = images[x];
   }

   randImg();


var imagesr = [
    "",
    "01b.jpg",
    "02b.jpg",
    "03b.jpg"];

function randImgr() {
    var sizer = imagesr.length
    var y = Math.floor(sizer * Math.random())
    document.getElementById('imager').src = imagesr[y];
    }

    randImgr();
```

HTML

```
<body  onload="randImg()" onload="randImg()">
```

on the page just can show one image. the error message is 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"

If i delete one part of JS, it works fine.

I don't know too much about JS, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: You might have no `<img id="image" />` in the `body`

Comment: Do you have the elements `#image` and `#imager` in your HTML? Are they dynamically generated?